# Change the value of CJuiSlider with input box value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have a CJuiSlider that works fine..
when slider value changed that value get displayed in input box..
up to this is fine,
now i want totally different of this. i.e. when value changed in the input box (by typing value using keyboard) then slider also change its value according to the value of the input box..

my code is--

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSlider', array(
'value'=>1,
'id'=>'planSlider',
 'change'=>'js:function{$("#plan_year").value($("#planSlider").slider( "option", "value" ));}',


// additional javascript options for the slider plugin
'options'=>array(
    'min'=>1,
     'max'=>100,
    'slide'=>'js:function(event, ui) { $("#plan_year").val(ui.value);}', 

    //'onchange'=>'js:function{$("#plan_year").value($("#planSlider").slider( "option", "value" ));}',
  ),
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
      'style'=>'height:12px; width:500px'
   ),
 ));
?>
<input type="text" name="Calculator[plan_year]" id="plan_year" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
```

here i am using java script as **'change'=>'js:function{$("#plan_year").value($("#planSlider").slider( "option", "value" ));}',**

what is missing in my code??
help..
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<input onkeyup="$('#planSlider').slider('value', this.value);" type="text" name="Calculator[plan_year]" value="1" id="plan_year" style=" color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
```